# Simulate Windows 8.1 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.  I can test my <s>UWP</s> **"Universal Windows"** app using the emulator for Windows Phone 8.1 and 10.  I can also test it using the simulator for Windows 10.  Is it possible to test it using a simulator for Windows 8.1?

*CORRECTION:

I used the wrong terminology.  I meant to say Universal Windows app instead of UWP.  Yes, a UWP app is for Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile only.  What I meant is a Universal Windows app targeted for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, that also is capable of being run on Windows 10 and Windows 10 Mobile.

Is the answer still the same?

Comment: Windows 8.1 does not run UWP apps. It runs Windows 8 Store apps which are similar, but not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, Visual Studio's 'emulator' for Windows Desktop is just a virtual instance of installed OS, not an emulator. Thus, you can't use the Win8.1 'emulator' of Visual studio on Windows 10 - because no Win8.1 installed. You should consider another options - like as VM, actual system, etc.

edit - My answer is applicable for Win8.1 Universal App. You can run your Win8.1 Universal app with Win10 or Visual studio Win10 simulator(like as size-different tablet emulation), but Visual Studio Win8.1 simulator is not available on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8.1 doesn't support UWP apps.

> If you choose to develop Universal Windows apps with Visual Studio
>   2015 on a platform other than Windows 10, these are the restrictions:
>
> 1. Windows 8.1: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows    10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but
>      not the    simulator.
> 2. Windows 7: You can’t run the app locally (only on a remote Windows
>      10 device). You can’t use the emulators or the simulator in Visual
>      Studio either.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx)